# CodeMirror - cut value and append text

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Is there a way to cut the value by line numbers?
For example, here's my editor's text area:

```
initial function () {
  a = '1';
  b = '2';
}
```

I will use getRange() to get the value inside initial function from editor, here's what I want to get:

```
a = '1';
b = '2';
```

Right now I want to append text to each line of value:

```
let val = cm.getRange({line: 0, ch: 0}, {line: cm.lineCount()-1, ch: 0});
val = 'someText' + val.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

I will get something like this

```
someTexta='1';b='2';
```

But what I want is

```
someTexta = '1';
someTextb = '2';
```

Is there a way in codemirror to cut value into array or something else by lines?

Comment: what is `val` before you use replace on it?

Comment: val will get the range of the code, so I'll get   a = '1';
  b = '2'; include the indent.

Comment: does it also include the line break?

Comment: yes it's included

Comment: does this work for you `val = val.split(/\n/).map(line => line ? "someText" +line.trim() : line).join('\n');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string into separate lines using `.split(/\n/)`. This will give you an element in an array for each line. Then, you can `.map()` each line into a string with `"someText` prepended to it (only if that line is valid - hence the `line ?` check). Then, you can convert it back into a string using `.join('\n')`. See example below:

```js
let val = ` a = '1';
  b = '2';`;
val = val.split(/\n/).map(line => line ? "someText" +line.trim() : line).join('\n');

console.log(val);
```